# Set button pressed from ViewFlipper (Android)

Tags: android, button, viewflipper

I'm making an Android app and have a strange problem. I need a ViewFlipper for 5 tabs. I made a layout for a page with 5 buttons. I used `OnClickListener` and flipping tabs works ok, but I need to `setPressed(true)` for a button, and I can't do that. There is a repaint problem or something. I looked for solution on the net but no one else has this problem? What did I do wrong?

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    factory = getLayoutInflater();
        skin = factory.inflate(R.layout.skin_tab_raspored, null);

    vremelayout = (LinearLayout) skin.findViewById(R.id.vreme);
    infolayout = (LinearLayout) skin.findViewById(R.id.info);

        buttons[0] = (Button) skin.findViewById(R.id.pon);
        buttons[1] = (Button) skin.findViewById(R.id.uto);
        buttons[2] = (Button) skin.findViewById(R.id.sre);
        buttons[3] = (Button) skin.findViewById(R.id.cet);
        buttons[4] = (Button) skin.findViewById(R.id.pet);

        buttons[0].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                flipper_info.setDisplayedChild(0);
                buttons[currentTab].setPressed(false);
                currentTab = 0;
                buttons[0].setPressed(true);
            }
        });
        buttons[1].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                flipper_info.setDisplayedChild(1);
                buttons[currentTab].setPressed(false);
                currentTab = 1;
                buttons[1].setPressed(true);
            }
        });
        buttons[2].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                flipper_info.setDisplayedChild(2);
                buttons[currentTab].setPressed(false);
                currentTab = 2;
                buttons[2].setPressed(true);
            }
        });
        buttons[3].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                flipper_info.setDisplayedChild(3);
                buttons[currentTab].setPressed(false);
                currentTab = 3;
                buttons[3].setPressed(true);
            }
        });
        buttons[4].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                flipper_info.setDisplayedChild(4);
                buttons[currentTab].setPressed(false);
                currentTab = 4;
                buttons[4].setPressed(true);
            }
        });

        buttons[0].setPressed(true);

        add_time(); //adding content to vremelayout

        flipper_info = new ViewFlipper(this);

        flipper_info.addView(this.addContentToInfo(Dan.pon));//adding content to infolayout
        flipper_info.addView(this.addContentToInfo(Dan.uto));
        flipper_info.addView(this.addContentToInfo(Dan.sre));
        flipper_info.addView(this.addContentToInfo(Dan.cet));
        flipper_info.addView(this.addContentToInfo(Dan.pet));

        infolayout.addView(flipper_info);

        setContentView(skin);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use setEnabled() insted of setPressed inside every clickListener

```
            flipper_info.setDisplayedChild(0);
            buttons[currentTab].setEnabled(true);
            currentTab = 0;
            buttons[0].setEnabled(false);
```

**OR**

For Background color change use toggleButton , it will allow you to set selector for on/off state ... toggle states inside clickListener .

Comment: Tnx to this, but i can't use this. I need change bgd of button and for that use selector. Can't get in selector(item) this enabled attribute?

Comment: Ya ToggleButton works...tnx...also must use enable and setChecked for other 4 buttons cause need some radio button still of buttons :P
After all I saw that I probably could use radio buttons, buy to add them my skin :P

Comment: sorry, I am new on this beautiful site :P